# Yii2 data attributes handled by the framework

Tags: yii2, custom-data-attribute

So, if there is a need to place a link somewhere in some template, and want it work by post method, i just add a data-method = 'post' attribute. 
If i want to send some parameters, then just add data-params-param1 = "param1Value" attribute.
If i need a confirmation before this link work - add data-confirm = "Some comfirmation message" attribute.
The question is: what other data-* attributes i can use when developing with Yii2, or where i can find information.
I have tried to google, look in Yii2 api - no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no documentation for this at the moment. It's only mentioned in few places.

Based on the current [yii.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.9/framework/assets/yii.js), [yii,captcha.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.9/framework/assets/yii.captcha.js), and [yii.gridView.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.9/framework/assets/yii.gridView.js) these `data-*` are specially handled:

- form
- method
- params
- pjax
- pjax-push-state
- pjax-replace-state
- pjax-timeout
- pjax-scrollto
- pjax-push-redirect
- pjax-replace-redirect
- pjax-skip-outer-containers
- pjax-container
- yiiActiveForm
- yiiSubmitFinalizePromise
- yiiCaptcha
- key

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!